# Annoying Visual Studio IDE Highlighting Question

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2010 I have applied a different color scheme and installed a productivity tool (Teleriks JustCode)... now where every my cursor is the background color of the entire line is light gray. It's really annoying and I'm not sure what is causing it. Has anyone seen this? If so do you know how to turn it off?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's the `Highlight current line` option of **Resharper** or **Productivity Power Tools**

#### Deactivate in Resharper

```
Resharper > Options > Editor > Untick "Highlight current line"
```

#### Deactivate in Productivity Power Tools

```
Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools > "Highlight current line" to Off
```

Comment: awesome! thank you so much! that has been bugging me forever!

Comment: "you must restart visual studio for the changes to take effect"?! #lame

Answer (score 1):

Tools: Options: Environment: Fonts and Colors: Current Line (x2).

Yes, I have seen this, and yes, I have turned it off :-)

Comment: +1, i've also experienced this and it can be solved just like you suggested.